# Changinge case of tablenames inside stored procedure of mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am here to change the uppercase table name present in the stored procedures. I have got nearly 100 stored procedures. is there any shortcut way so that i can change all the uppercase table names to lowercase within short time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you could mysqldump the procedures and triggers, something like this:

```
mysqldump --routines --no-create-info --no-data --no-create-db --skip-opt <database> > outputfile.sql
```

Then do your find/replace with uppercase on that dump file and then reload the procedures/triggers back into your DB.

Comment: how can i use it? where to write it... i tried it in mysql console as well in sqlyog query but not luck

Comment: got the clue of dumping from some other software and did work

Answer (score 0):

I would write something that would iterate through some folder (where these files are) then change the case to what you needed it to be.  I'm not exactly sure why you want to change the case though.

Comment: Coz in linux hosting... its case sensitive and what's the file location